# OutOfMemoryError while running robot selenium tests for a maven project on jenkins?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I have a huge maven project where I have robotframework frontend tests. I've configgured my maven integration-test phase to start a tomcat7 instance, run the tests and stop the tomcat.

All this works fine on my local computer but once I make jenkins build the same task it always fails on `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`.
I've tried tuning the PermGen of my jenkins installation and of the tomcat process that maven should start, with no luck

I'm beginning to doubt my setup here and would like some insight on how to acomplish this.

Comment: Which project throws the Error? The maven build or the spawned tomcat? Have you adjusted MAVEN_OPTS either globally or for your jenkins job?

Comment: I think it's the spawned tomcat, I've tried adjusting both globally and for the singel job

Comment: can you include the log context of the error?